# CSS3 rotate animation not working in chrome

Tags: css

CSS3:

```
.icon-refresh-animate {
    -webkit-animation: rotate 15s linear infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: rotate 15s linear infinite alternate;
    -ms-animation: rotate 15s linear infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: rotate 15s linear infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes "rotate" {
  from { transform: scale( 1 ) rotate( 0deg );   }
  to   { transform: scale( 1 ) rotate( 360deg ); }
}
```

HTML:

```
    <span class="btn btn-success active" data-restrict data-access="scouter recruiter admin" data-ng-if="!layout.syncProgress">
        <i class="icon-refresh icon-refresh-animate" > {{'REFRESHDATAPROGRESS' | translate}}</i>
    </span>
```

Just wouldn't do a thing.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please elaborate, perhaps even post an answer, I am quite new to animations, chrome web tools css inspector seems to show that everything is fine.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LEKrm/ - works here. it seems you cannot transform inline elements

Comment: So the reason is that the icon is inside of a button? :(

Comment: no, the reason is that the `i` is considered part of phrasing content, therefor `inline` by default. Just set it to `inline-block` and you're fine (Chrome doesn't seem to support transforms on inline elements yet)

Comment: Argh, now the button is rotating along with the icon.
Unless I take the icon out of the button

Answer (score 3):

For me it's working fine on chrome but not working on firefox and the reason I found is that you have missed this:

```
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  from { -moz-transform: scale( 1 ) rotate( 0deg );   }
  to   { -moz-transform: scale( 1 ) rotate( 360deg ); }
}
```

Comment: Chrome is webkit sir, not mozilla, thanks for taking the time for forming this answer though (+)

Comment: I'm not sure that moz needs a prefix

Comment: I gave the solution for firefox, cuz it wasn't working on firefox, check the fiddle jsfiddle.net/LEKrm given by onetrickpony in third comment below question.

Comment: No, it is not working on chrome, and the reason is noted in the comments to the question it self.